# Why is an endpoint-specific DNS hostname resolving on the open internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

For work, I created an [interface endpoint with private dns enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html).  AWS generated endpoint-specific DNS hostnames as expected.  However, I expect those DNS addresses to be accessible only within my VPC and instead I see they resolve on the public internet.  By "public internet" I mean that my personal (non-work) laptop can resolve the DNS hostname when tethered to my non-work cell phone (no VPN, no work access).  Major-league surprise!

I'm obfuscating the DNS name for this example, but basically the following command worked from a public network when I expected it to fail:

```
c:\>nslookup vpce-05df6-ug9qu.ec2.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com
Server: Unknown
Address: 192.168.43.254

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: vpce-05df6-ug9qu.ec2.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com
Addresses: 10.137.90.25
           10.137.95.40
```

Again, I've obfuscated/altered the above DNS name and IP answers because I don't want the real values posted in this question, but the above is sufficient to clarify that surprisingly the address did resolve. I had instead expected nslookup would say:

> *** Unknown can't find vpce-05df6-ug9qu.ec2.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com: Non-existent domain

Why is this?

Comment: Since you have masked the actual addresses, verify that they are on 10.x.x.x. These are private IP addresses that cannot be accessed from the public Internet. Edit your question and provide more details on how (where) you are resolving the DNS hostname. Do you have a VPN linking your network to your VPC? The issue is why a Private Hosted Zone is working. There must be a name server path from your local name server (192.168.43.254) to the name servers for your Private Hosted Zone. Normally this requires a forwarder.

Comment: you can map any valid dns entry to any valid IP address (internal or external) and unless there is some special dns config it will resolve... You obviously can't route to a private address even if it resolves so just because people can see the IP it won't help them in anything other than reconnaissance of your setup.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've updated my question to clarify "public internet".  A co-worker suggested perhaps it resolves because of how Amazon handles DNS entries...but that the IP address would nevertheless not be reachable by any public means.

Comment: I do not see any added information to help with an answer. I am not able to help as the details required to create an answer are missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolving because the DNS entry is a fully qualified domain name (FQDN).

You can point a FQDN to any destination and when a DNS query is executed, it will return the private address. If the address is a private IP, and the request request comes from a node on your private network your request will resolve to your private IP.

Comment: Hmm, just because it's an FQDN doesn't mean it is resolvable.  I mean this random entry I just made up http://alsdfjlsajflafjdaslkfjd.com is an FQDN but is not resolvable.  AWS could have made it private i.e. not publicly resolvable, irrespective of its FQDN status but they didn't.  The question is why?

Comment: Private Hosted Zone are not accessible from the public Internet. This would disclose potentially private information such as host names.

Comment: do you find any explanation to this? any way to hide this?